# Refresh UITableView not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7

In the view controller there is a UITableView, in last section last row, there is a Facebook sign in and sign out button as toggle. If user signed in it automatically turn to sign out and vice versa. The problem is when signing in control goes out of app in safari then comes back and view automatically refreshes, but when signing out UITableView doesn't reload. Below is code i'm using.

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
        for (cookie in [storage cookies])
        {
            NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
            NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
            if(domainRange.length > 0)
            {
                [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
                isFb = 0;
                [tableView_detailsEdit reloadData];
                [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            }
        }
        isFb = 0;

        [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        [tableView_detailsEdit reloadData];
```

Problem is UITableView delegate methods not getting called. Thus, text on cell in table view doesn't gets change after sign out to sign in.
Please guide for above.

Comment: Have you set yourself (the view controller) or whatever object implements the delegate methods as the delegate of the table view?

Comment: @HAS Yes delegates are set that's why tableview is working,if i scroll uitableview then value change but not automatically by calling reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

     [tableView_detailsEdit reloadData];

}];
```

Or

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds *  NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     [tableView_detailsEdit reloadData];
});
```